# Двоеточие в "Дорога обвивалась вокруг ее скалистого подножья и уходила под ворота: змея в расселину."

Tags: пунктуация

Мне кажется, тут уместней тире. Если ошибаюсь, то почему? Если не ошибаюсь, почему в "Приглашении на казнь" использован вариант с двоеточием?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А мне кажется, что здесь лучше использовать обычный сравнительный союз. Если нужна авторская пауза, то можно поставить перед оборотом тире:

(1) Дорога обвивалась вокруг ее скалистого подножья и уходила под ворота, как змея в расселину.

(2) Дорога обвивалась вокруг ее скалистого подножья и уходила под ворота — как змея в расселину.”

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ**

По правилам оба варианта (с тире и двоеточием)  возможны, поэтому оставлен авторский вариант:  Дорога обвивалась вокруг ее скалистого подножья и уходила под ворота:  змея в расселину.

Вторая часть — это авторское неполное предложение примерно такого содержания: "так змея уползает в расселину".

**Двоеточие** позволяет сделать предупредительную паузу **перед сравнением, подчеркивает его значимость**.

Если поставить **тире**, то предложение приобретает присоединительный характер **попутного замечания**.

Comment: Только вопрос не в этом: я не спрашиваю как здесь заменить, а делаю акцент на том, из каких соображений редакторы решили оставить в этом предложении двоеточие. Есть ли на то пунктуационные обоснования? Если нет, то хотелось бы услышать чёткое нет, если да, то интересно по какому правилу.

Answer (score 2):

У Набокова нет ничего случайного.Произведение сложное для понимания, по крайней мере для меня, я не очень люблю всякую мистику, а это-сплошная гносеология, поэтому какие-то детали он объясняет. Вот и здесь вторая часть поясняет первую, иначе мы не поймём, что это символ.

Герой заточён в крепость за «гносеологическую гнусность». «Дорога обвивалась вокруг ее скалистого подножья и уходила под ворота: змея в расселину». «Змея»
— центральный гностический символ, царь тьмы и зла, «владеющий всем созданным под небесами,... окружающий сферу,... лежащий снаружи,... чей хвост покоится в собственной пасти» Крепость, в которой каждый коридор приводит Цинцинната обратно в камеру, построена наподобие гностического лабиринта.

Получается:«Дорога обвивалась вокруг ее скалистого подножья и уходила под ворота, а именно: змея уходила в расселину, чтобы вернуться».Герой это понимает, а мы нет, вот нам и даётся пояснение.